# NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mViewFlags'

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, viewgroup

My app was working fine, and I then included the support design library in the build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

Android Studio prompted to download more components and after that I started seeing way too many of these crashes when navigation b/w different fragments

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.presdo.match.matchtemplate, PID: 23339
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mViewFlags' on a null object reference
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3197)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:598)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14167)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3389)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3368)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14127)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14189)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:273)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:279)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:318)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2530)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1982)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is my build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.0'
```

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242776/android-viewgroup-crash-attempt-to-read-from-field-int-android-view-view-mview) and I am not yet sure if it has something to do with my code.

Now, even if I remove the google design support library, I see the crashes, and not able to predict when they happen, since there is no reference to my project's code base in the stacktrace.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I made changes to the Gradle to make the support library versions consistent, and I don't see the crashes anymore. Here is a snippet

```
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.2.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:percent:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to mix versions from different support libraries, since they have interdependencies that may not work across versions.

I'd try updating them all to 23.2.1, rather than mixing 23.0, 23.1 & 23.2

Comment: Thanks Steve. This actually resolved my issue. I now have them all set to 23.2.1

Answer (score 4):

It is (again) an animation issue. You probably have some custom animations set with

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations();
```

Remove them and it works again. Congratulations, you now have fragment transitions like 5 years ago.

Edit : a better way is to restore your old repository, by downloading

http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r26.zip

and replacing everything in

```
/Users/.../Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository
```

Took it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203546#makechanges).

Comment: Yes, There are customAnimations b/w fragments. It's done like this


`FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left_fast, R.anim.slide_out_left_fast);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, <fragment-reference>);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();`


I am curious to know why you mentioned "you now have fragment transitions like 5 years ago."

Comment: You have to remove the custom animations. When you have no animations running it will work. But it will look like Android from 5 years ago, bad, with no animations. It was... a joke.

Comment: Hah! Alright :) Turned out to be an issue with my usage of different versions of the support library.

Comment: @ElDuderino sorry for bumping in after 2 years. Just wondering if there is any other way to solve this? I am having same issue but don't want to remove animations.

Comment: @ZassX sry, not working in Android anymore, don't know what's the current state, but did you try to download and install http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r26.zip ?