# ViewPager api crashes app once 2 fragment load in viewpager with fragmentstatepager adapter?

Tags: android, crash, android-viewpager

I am trying to load 3 fragments using viewpager with tab but suddenly it start to crashing app. earlier it was working fine and i have not changes anything in this.

```
09-12 23:27:40.466 6724-6724/com.**.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                             Process: com.spoof.app, PID: 6724
                                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.View.mViewFlags' on a null object reference
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3690)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16130)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3711)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3691)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16130)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3711)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3691)
                                                                 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16130)
                                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
                                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
                                                                 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2800)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2608)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2215)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
                                                                 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
09-12 23:2
```

Comment: this wil help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242776/android-viewgroup-crash-attempt-to-read-from-field-int-android-view-view-mview

Comment: Nothing worked for me tired why this happening

Comment: post your fragment so people can help

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs  Hey thanks for comment it was SVPROGRESSHUD library issue just because of that this error came. I created custom progressdialog and it is solved.